# Как правильно вырезать слово начинающееся с некоторым набором букв из текста

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

То есть есть текст

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure expedita laborum, ad delectus cupiditate`

Есть string с буквами через запятую, разбиваю и получаю массив
`"re, co, cu"`

```
def splitString(string):
    return (map(
        lambda x:
        x.strip(), string.split(',')
    ))
```

`['re', 'co', 'cu']`

И нужно вырезать оттуда `Lorem`, `consectetur`, `cupiditate`, `Iure`

Я сделал такой вариант с регулярками

`"(([\S]+)?(%s)([\S]+)?)" % "|".join((arr))`

Потом просто replace, а после сборка для удаления двойных пробелов

И после исправил на другую функцию для нахождения с большой буквы

```
def splitStringUpper(string):
    string = tuple(map(
            lambda x:
            x.strip(), string.split(',')
    ))
    return string  + tuple(map(lambda x: x[0].upper() + x[1:], string))
```

И получаю массив `['re', 'co', 'cu', 'Re', 'Co', 'Cu']`

Есть ли вариант другого решения, без увлечения массива в два раза

Comment: [А вот такой вариант подойдёт?](http://rextester.com/WKAWKW19622)

Comment: спасибо, в двух местах улучшил мой код, а то я еще извращенным методом собирал это все

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я предлагаю использовать регулярное выражение с альтернативной группой, которое будет искать любые 0 и более цифробуквенных символов (плюс символ подчёркивания) до  и после любой из подстроки `re`, `co` и `cu` с регистронезависимым флагом:

```
import re
s = "re, co, cu"
i = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure expedita laborum, ad delectus cupiditate"
result = re.findall(r'(?ui)\w*(?:{})\w*'.format(s.replace(", ", "|")), i)
print(result)
# => ['Lorem', 'consectetur', 'Iure', 'cupiditate']
```

См. [демо на Python](http://rextester.com/RFLTC41493)

**Подробности**

- `s.replace(", ", "|")`  - сделает из `re, co, cu` `re|co|cu`, т.е. список альтернатив
- `(?ui)` - модификатор `re.I` и `r.U` (не требуется в Python 3, так как используется по умолчанию)
- `\w*` - 1 и более букв, цифр или `_`
- `(?:{})` -> `(?:re|co|cu)` - незахватвающая подмаска, находит одну из перечисленных альтернатив
- `\w*` - 1 и более букв, цифр или `_`

[Демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/ntFZPq/1)

Если нужно найти только буквенный "слова", замените `\w` на `[^\W\d_]`.

Если количество запятых и пробелов может быть неизвестно, вместо `s.replace(", ", "|")` используйте `re.sub(r'\s*,+\s*', '|' s)` (или даже `r'\s*,[,\s]*'`).